# Singleton design-pattern for Firestore Document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document for each user in my 'users' collection in Firestore. This document also stores some persistent state information about the user, which can also change because of external events. Most of my activities reference this data so I decided to use a singleton to reference the user details and attach a listener to notify activities so that only updated information is used. I'm using [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36120/singleton-holding-and-notifying-registered-listeners) as a template for my implementation.

```
public interface IUserUpdateListener
{
    void onSuccess(User user);
    void onFailure(FirebaseException e);
}
```

The methods that I'm using to handle the listener

```
private static List<IUserUpdateListener> _listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

public static void removeUserUpdateListener(final IUserUpdateListener listener)
{
    if (null != listener)
    {
        _listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

public static void addUserUpdateListener(final IUserUpdateListener listener)
{
    if(USER_INSTANCE != null)
    {
        if (null != listener)
        {
            _listeners.add(listener);
        }

        return;
    }

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection(Collections.USERS)
            .document(firebaseUser.getUid())
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e)
                {
                    if(e != null)
                    {
                        for(IUserUpdateListener listenerItem : _listeners)
                        {
                            listenerItem.onFailure(e);
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    USER_INSTANCE = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                    for(IUserUpdateListener listenerItem : _listeners)
                    {
                        listenerItem.onUpdate(USER_INSTANCE);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

How do I make it such that I don't have to explicitly detach listeners when the activity is not running? Also is there any unexpected behavior this code can run into?